# Inline VF page/section not visible on pagelayout

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, inline-visualforce

I have an inline VF page section on account page layout. The same inline VF is visible on IE and Mozilla.

I am very sure that I am not missing anything on the access front, since the same inline VF is visible on IE and Mozilla.

Any advice or pointers that I need to look into?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add related code here?

Comment: which browser its missing?

Comment: Google Chrome - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1LRAA0

Comment: You could post that as an answer to your question as that might help others

Comment: It is fixed now: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=308402

Answer (score 1):

This is posted as a Known issue with work around.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1LRAA0